# How To Set MySql SQL_MODE to ANSI from PHP

Tags: php, mysqli

MySQL Command:

```
set @session sql_mode = ANSI;
```

What is the corresponding PHP Command??

This Approach Does Not Seem To Work:

```
$conn= new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "DB");
$conn->options(MYSQLI_INIT_COMMAND, "SET SQL_MODE = 'ANSI'");
```

Comment: Looking at the manual - I don't think the options method is meant for this:  http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up using mysqli_init instead of new mysqli() and everything worked fine.

Comment: Please who exactly what you did

Comment: can you explain with example .

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you have missed the scope variable,try this:

SET GLOBAL SQL_MODE = 'ANSI'

Comment: It did not work when I tried it in mysql 5.7 via mysqli

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for you? (Sorry, can't test at the moment)

```
$conn->query("set @session sql_mode = ANSI;");
```

Comment: It did not work when I tried it in mysql 5.7 via mysqli