# Set sql_mode “blank” in MySQL 5.7 use only mysqli_query

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

**Relative answer search**
I tried all questions & answers related this topic.

1. [setting global sql_mode in mysql](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2317650/setting-global-sql-mode-in-mysql)
2. https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/109053/set-sql-mode-blank-after-upgrading-to-mysql-5-6
3. [How To Set MySql SQL_MODE to ANSI from PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2385243/how-to-set-mysql-sql-mode-to-ansi-from-php)
4. http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.options.php

**I want to** update global variable in  mysql `sql_mode = ''`.

After upgrading MySQL from 5.5 to 5.7.15, some our app face to problem and need set sql_mode to blank to solve this issue. I added sql_mode = '' but there was no effect on the mysql setting.

How do I keep the sql_mode blank ?

***tired Code***

```
$db = new DB_Sql();
$db->Host  = "172.**.**.**";
$db->Database   = "MyDatabase";
$db->User   = "root";
$db->Password   = "MyPassword";

global $ourFileName,$link;  
         
$SITE_URL="http://".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST];
$SITE_HTTPS_URL="http://".$_SERVER[HTTP_HOST];

$ourFileName = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/Log/MaintenaceLogFiles.txt"; 

 $ndb=$mdb=$db; 
 
 $link=mysqli_connect($db->Host, $db->User, $db->Password,$db->Database);

    if(mysqli_connect_errno())
    {
    echo '<p>Error: Unable to connect to MySQL: '.mysqli_connect_error().'</p>';
    }
    
  mysqli_query($link,"set sql_mode = '' ") or die(mysqli_error());
```

**Note:** **Using only** `mysqli_query` **not use** `.cnf`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Why do you think it doesn't work?

It works for me all right

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
$db=mysqli_connect($db->Host, $db->User, $db->Password,$db->Database);
$db->set_charset("utf8mb4");

$row = $db->query("SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'")->fetch_row();
var_dump($row[1]);

$db->query("SET SESSION sql_mode=''");

$row = $db->query("SHOW VARIABLES LIKE 'sql_mode'")->fetch_row();
var_dump($row[1]);
```

outputs

```
string(62) "STRICT_TRANS_TABLES,NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER,NO_ENGINE_SUBSTITUTION"
string(0) ""
```

if, for some reason, you want to set it global (while you shouldn't run your queries under root)

```
$mysqli->query("SET GLOBAL sql_mode='', SESSION sql_mode=''");
```

Comment: thank for answer . i tried but update a simple  variables `sql_mode` not change global variables . i update global variables

Comment: i check my update global  variable  `sql_mode` . `select  @@sql_mode;` not be null

Comment: to update a global variable you should update a global variable. but you are updating a session variable in your code. just make your mind

Comment: i set user `customuser`  in phpmyadmin not (`root`user use ) . so i can't updated global variable so please help

Comment: then set it to session